# Weeks since larger drop

Tags: google-sheets

### Data

Each value in `B` is the amount that the Federal Reserve balance sheet changed for a given week.

[image]

### Largest drop since...

This past week, the balance sheet decreased by $31,617.

This is the largest drop since Dec 29th.

These values are highlighted in the data above.

### Question

It would be nice to have a column that calculates this for us. I.e. something like *weeks since larger drop*.

Example with the last 4 manually filled out:

[image]

So, on `2022-05-25` when the balance sheet dropped `$31,617`, it was the biggest drop since `2021-12-29`. And it had been `21` weeks since that larger drop.

What's a good way to have a formula that calculates these extra columns?

### Logic

Seems like the logic should be:

- Search backward for the lower value
- Get the date at that row
- Compute date diff. Find number of weeks from that.

### Link to sheet

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1utweqV2KnH5GQJIDL4DYLqMrFdBHrFuU35S6vGLbONA/edit?usp=sharing) to the Google Sheet shown above, in case you'd like to experiment on the data.

Comment: What qualifies as a large drop? From what I can see, row 132 is a pretty large drop, comparatively larger than row 140 anyways.

Comment: I understood that it is necessary to take into consideration the FIRST drop larger than the current one among the previous ones

Comment: @Daniele, For now I've used a C# program to generate the additional columns. It's provided below.

Comment: @Daniele, I've also set this up in Excel:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164945/293007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula for "Last Larger Date" works on google sheet (it must be dragged) and gives a result that matches the image of your first post:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(IF(
$B2="","",
IF($B2 > 0, 
LOOKUP(2, 1 / (N($B1:B$2) > $B2), IF($B1:B$2<0,$A1:A$2,)), 
LOOKUP(2, 1 / (N($B1:B$2) < $B2), $A1:A$2)
))))
```

for the week count this calculation is enough (no need to drag it):

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C<>"",DIVIDE(A2:A-C2:C,7),))
```

[image: drop]

Comment: Very nice Daniele! Looks similar to the Excel formulas.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've used a C# program to import the CSV data and output a new CSV file with the additional columns.

**Program:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace WalclWeeksSinceLarger
{
    public class FedBalanceSheetCsvRow
    {
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(0)] public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Index(1)] public decimal Change { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Change { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLarger { get; set; }
        public int WeeksSinceLarger { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { };

            // From:
            // 
            //     https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=PRKH

            var fed_balance_sheet_items =
                new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"..\..\..\WALCL.csv"), config)
                .GetRecords<FedBalanceSheetCsvRow>()
                .ToList();

            var result = fed_balance_sheet_items.Select(item => 
            {
                var ls = fed_balance_sheet_items.TakeWhile(elt => elt.Date < item.Date).Reverse().ToList();

                var null_data = new Data()
                {
                    Date = item.Date,
                    Change = item.Change
                };

                if (item.Change == 0) return null_data;
               
                var obj = item.Change > 0 ?
                    ls.FirstOrDefault(elt => elt.Change > item.Change) :
                    ls.FirstOrDefault(elt => elt.Change < item.Change);

                if (obj == null) return null_data;

                return new Data()
                { 
                    Date = item.Date,
                    Change = item.Change,
                    LastLarger = obj.Date,
                    WeeksSinceLarger = (int)(item.Date - obj.Date).TotalDays / 7
                };
            });


            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\..\out.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                csv.WriteRecords(result);
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to set this up in Excel.

Note the three additional columns below:

[image]

The data is in an Excel table (note the structured references).

## Formulas

**LAST LARGER**

```
= IF( [@[WALCL_CHG]] > 0,
    LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 > [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $B$2:B1015),
    LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 < [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $B$2:B1015))
```

**DATE OF LAST LARGER**

```
= IF( [@[WALCL_CHG]] > 0,
    LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 > [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $A$2:A1015),
    LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 < [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $A$2:A1015))
```

**WEEKS SINCE LARGER**

```
= IF( [@[WALCL_CHG]] > 0,
    DATEDIF(LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 > [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $A$2:A1015), [@DATE], "d") / 7,
    DATEDIF(LOOKUP(2, 1 / ($B$2:B1015 < [@[WALCL_CHG]]), $A$2:A1015), [@DATE], "d") / 7)
```

## Notes

The above formulas do not appear to work in Google Sheets.

## Example file

[Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjlM3TqVAvfOh8wquN-T-K9iUUx14A?e=LR1Wg5) to spreadsheet.

Comment: date was in A in your linked file, now it is in B... wich is the formula for A? please post a link to the new (not working) file

Comment: @Daniele, Here ya go: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjlM3TqVAvfOh8wquN-T-K9iUUx14A?e=LR1Wg5